# Reinstalling Win10 to different hard drive - How do I activate?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, ssd, windows-installation, reinstall

After letting my PC get old for 7 years, I'm thinking about upgrading and moving to an SSD drive. I'm concerned about re-installing Windows 10 though. Back in the day it used to be simple: You went to your PC settings, checked the activation code, reinstalled Windows and were all set. This time it's different for me.

I moved from a Windows 8 (activated with an oldschool activation code) to Windows 10 when it was a free upgrade. However, now I can't see the activation code under settings, as it says "Windows is activated with a digital licence linked to you Microsoft account".

So, how does a new install work in this case? I buy a new SSD, burn myself a Win10 installer disc and then what? Will my original Win8 activation code work? Or will I have to log in and Windows will fetch the license info from online? Or will it mess around with my for installing Win10 twice (although I think the licence is tied to the motherboard, not sure)? I'm pretty sure I can figure it out once I get there, just want to be a bit more informed before I start installing stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 10 activation process was designed to be simpler, not more complicated. Product keys are terrible, and people lose them or they get ruined. From a licensing standpoint it enables people to violate their license agreement, by moving OEM keys to a different computer. So Microsoft made it better for them and the consumer.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, your Windows 8 key will activate Windows 10 again.
2. However, you won’t need it, because Windows 10 will activate automatically with your digital license when it recognizes that it’s the same computer that was activated previously.

Use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to create new installation media. Reinstall the same version (Home / Pro) and it will reactivate on its own.